# How to improve authentication in a Perl Dancer app

Tags: web-services, perl, authentication, active-directory, dancer

I am working on a Perl Dancer web application that needs to accomplish two things in terms of authentication:

1. authenticate users based on Active Directory for access to the application
2. authenticate as the user to access a couple of .NET web services.

The application is being hosted as a CGI application by Apache on a Linux box, and I do not have much control over Apache's configuration.

Below is the workflow of the currently working application:

1. Display a login page to the user
2. When the user submits the form, use [Authen::Simple::ActiveDirectory](http://search.cpan.org/~chansen/Authen-Simple-LDAP-0.3/lib/Authen/Simple/ActiveDirectory.pm) to verify the account is valid
3. Store the user's credentials using [Dancer::Session::Cookie](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Dancer-Session-Cookie-0.18/lib/Dancer/Session/Cookie.pm) (encrypted cookies)
4. Display a search form to the user
5. When the user submits this form, use [Authen::NTLM](http://search.cpan.org/~markbush/NTLM-1.02/NTLM.pm) and [SOAP::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/~mkutter/SOAP-Lite-0.715/lib/SOAP/Lite.pm) to access the .NET services (similar to the example [here](http://lifo101.wordpress.com/2012/05/08/sharepoint-and-ntlmv2-with-soaplite/)) to perform a search
6. Display the results to the user

The handling of user credentials here concerns me, but I am generally new to web applications and authentication.  For a small internal application, is this okay?  If not, how do you suggest I improve this process?  Like I said, the application as outlined above works, but I feel like it could/should be improved.

Answer (score 1):

One (part of a) solution could be that you let your apache webserver handle the 
authentication. You could use [Kerberos](http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net/) for this. 
So only permitted users can access your application. In that 
case `$ENV{REMOTE_USER}` contains the username (e.g. foo.bar@MY.DOMAIN.COM).

If you need more information about the current user you can query your LDAP (containd in your Domain). I use a common (LDAP) user to get more information about the current user  foo.bar@MY.DOMAIN.COM.

I know that this is only the fist part. I do not have experience useing/passing Kerberos tickets by SOAP. But if you mange to handle this, you have a clean SSO solution.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

We do this in the Apache config.  It requires something like the below.  You'll need a read only password-less user to bind to Active Directory.

```
    AuthName "Active Directory"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPUrl ldap://server:389/OU=COMPANY,DC=COMPANY,DC=com?sAMAccountName,mail,name,extensionAttribute2,memberOf?base?(objectClass=user)
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=ReadOnlyUser,OU=ServiceAccounts,OU=Users,OU=XXX,OU=COMPANY,DC=COMPANY,DC=com"
    AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on 
    require valid-user
```